# SQL select statement optimizing (id, parent_id, child_ids)

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, select, optimization

we have a very old custom db (oracle, mysql, derby) with the restrictions: no new table fileds, no views, no functions, no procedures.

My table MYTABLE:

```
    | id | ... | parent_id |
    ------------------------
    | 1  | ... |           |
    | 2  | ... |    1      |
    | 3  | ... |    1      |
    | 4  | ... |    2      |
    | 5  | ... |    1      |
```

and I my first statement:

```
select * from MYTABLE where id in ('1','2','3','4','5');
```

give my 5 records.

Then I need the information about the first (no deeper) child ids.
My current solution:

```
for (record in records) {
    // get child ids as comma separated string list 
    // e.g. "2,3,5" for id 1
    String childIds = getChildIds(record.id);
}
```

with the second statement in getChildIds(record.Id):

```
select id from MYTABLE where parent_id='record.Id';
```

So I have 1 + 5 = 6 statements for the required information.

I'm looking for a solution to select the records from the following "imaginary" table with the "imaginary" field "child_ids":

```
| id | ... | parent_id | child_ids |
------------------------------------
| 1  | ... |           | 2,3,5     |
| 2  | ... |    1      | 4         |
| 3  | ... |    1      |           |
| 4  | ... |    2      |           |
| 5  | ... |    1      |           |
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can get this information with only one statement (or with 2 statements)?

Thanks for your help, Thomas

Comment: The last table is not a real table. I need (but I have not) this table for only a select statement.

Answer (score 0):

***FOR MYSQL:***

How about using the [**GROUP_CONCAT()**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function like the following:

```
SELECT id, parent_id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(child_id ORDER BY child_id SEPARATOR ',') AS child_ids 
FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE id IN ('1','2','3','4','5')
```

***FOR ORACLE:***

If you have a later version of Oracle you could use the [**LISTAGG()**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) function:

```
SELECT parent_id, 
       LISTAGG(child_id, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY child_id) "child_ids"
FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE id IN ('1','2','3','4','5')
GROUP BY parent_id
```

***FOR DERBY:***

I don't know anything about derby, but doing a little research it uses IBM DB2 SQL syntax.  So, maybe using a combination of [**XMLSERIALIZE()**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_xmlserialize.htm), [**XMLAGG()**](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0022183.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0/2-10-3-1-14), and [**XMLTEXT()**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0022196.html) will work for you:

```
SELECT parent_id,
       XMLSERIALIZE(XMLAGG(XMLTEXT(child_id) ORDER BY child_id) AS CLOB(30K))
FROM table GROUP BY parent_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'll test the solution tomorrow. 
Can I use this statement in all db (oracle, mysql, derby)?

Comment: Is there a statement for all db (oracle, mysql, derby)?
A solution without swicth-case would be perfect.

Comment: As far as I know there is no one solution for Oracle, MySQL and Derby.  Especially not without building your own custom functions.  All three of them are distinctively different when it comes to built in function support.